# Go application deployment in Bluemix fails

Tags: go, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am facing issues with pushing the sample Go applicaiton in Bluemix.

I will explain the steps I followed to push the applicaiton.

1. Created D:/goapp2016 and set it to GOPATH.
2. created src, pkg and bin folders in D:/goapp2016
3. In src, created "myapp" folder and written a sample app.go file.
4. Ran "go get" command inside GOPATH/src/myapp and that downloaded the libraries from Git in GOAPTH/src folder and mysql.a,native.a files in D:\goapp2016\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\ziutek\mymysql. And myapp.exe is also created in GOPATH/bin after running go get command.
5. Ran "godep save" command which created Godeps/Godeps.json and vendor/(dependent libraries) folder in GOPATH/src/myapp.
6. To push the application to bluemix, I  executed cf push command from GOPATH directory.

But, this is giving the below error.

```
-------> Buildpack version 1.7.5
file:///var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/e57c0cd5-3b42-424d-ad32-b0bee17b
c1b0_a25a466217b64d5e4d47a6796be8ab23e7b7eeaf/dependencies/https___pivotal-build
packs.s3.amazonaws.com_concourse-binaries_godep_godep-v62-linux-x64.tgz
-----> Installing go1.6... done
Downloaded [file:///var/vcap/data/dea_next/admin_buildpacks/e57c0cd5-3b42-424d-a
d32-b0bee17bc1b0_a25a466217b64d5e4d47a6796be8ab23e7b7eeaf/dependencies/https___s
torage.googleapis.com_golang_go1.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz]
 !
 !     Error: Cloud Foundry does not support the GB package manager
 !     We currently only support the 'Godep' package manager for go apps
 !     For support please file an issue: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-    buildpack/issues
 !
 Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
```

Directory Structure:

```
goapp2016/
    bin/
        godep.exe
        myapp.exe
    pkg/
        windows_amd64/
            github.com/
                tools/
                    godep/
                ziutek/
                    mymysql

    src/
        github.com/
            ziutek/

        myapp/  
            app.go
            Godeps/
                Godeps.json
            vendor/
                github.com/
                    ziutek/

    manifest.yml
    Procfile
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: I don't know bluemix and I don't know Godeps but my guess would be that Bluemix expects the Godeps-file (or directory) to be at the root-dir (so right next to your src-directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile file for the buildpack can be seen here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile

Dependency tool selection begins on [line 136](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/go-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile#L136), as long as there is a Godeps/Godeps.json file, the buildpack should used godeps, not GB. Are you sure you are pushing from the folder than contains the Godeps folder, that in turn contains the Godeps.json file?

Comment: Looking at the structure you posted, you should be pushing from goapp2016/src/myapp..

Comment: the problem is I was trying to push the app from goapp2016 folder which had the manifest/yml file (goapp is starter code from bluemix). Later I amended the the folder structure as in the question( which is not correct). The manifest.yml and Procfile should be inside myapp.  Now its working after pushing the app from myapp folder.